# How to access API data using vue.js with v-for loop

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, v-for

[Data into recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLSG.png) [API Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q0fZ.png) I am looping through some API data & cannot access a part of the object

```
 I am using v-for method in vue.js. In the main div I loop through using 
 the iterator recipe, it works for everything except for 
 analyzedInstructions.steps

<div class="food" v-for="(recipe,index) in recipes" 
  v-bind:recipe="recipe" 
  v-bind:index="index"
  v-bind:key="recipe.id">
      <p>{{ recipe.title }}</p>
        <p> Ready in: {{ recipe.readyInMinutes }} minutes</p>
        <p>Serve's up to {{ recipe.servings }}</p>
        <p v-for="(dish) in recipe.dishTypes" v-bind:key="dish.id" v- 
 bind:dish="dish">Dish Type: {{ dish }}</p>
        <p v-for="(occasion) in recipe.occasions" v- 
bind:key="occasion.id" 
v-bind:occasion="occasion">Occasions: {{ occasion }}</p>
        <p>Cooking Instructions: {{ recipe.instructions }}</p>
        <ul>
        <li v-for="(step) in recipe.analyzedInstructions.steps" v- 
 bind:key="step.id" v-bind:step="step">Analyzed Instructions: {{ 
 step.step 
}}</li>
        </ul>



  </div>
```

This is the api data
analyzedInstructions: [
{
name: "",
steps: [
{
number: 1,
step: lorem Ipsum

Nothing shows up after the

tag Cooking Instructions. No errors in console

Comment: the api data analyzedInstructions: [
{
name: "",
steps: [
{
number: 1,
step:

Comment: Can you share what is in between your script tags please?

Comment: Also can you share a console.log of the full `recipe` object please.

Comment: Can you show that part of your code when you put data into ``recipe``

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you need to look into docs about Reactivity in Vue.
You can't do like this inside your Vue component:

`recipe.analyzedInstructions = {whatever: 'it is'}`

You probably need `Vue.set()` and make sure your data is reactive.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats